# What is the default version of the nuget package when referenced with PackageReference in .NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I am trying to learn and understand nuget and msbuild in .NET Core by examining and manually editing project files (.csproj in .NET Core 2.2).
So when I create WebApi project, the .csproj file looks like this:

```xml
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"  />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Notice that there is no Version attribute specified for the first `PackageReference`. 
Now if I specify it to be the latest stable version 2.2.3 like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.3" />
```

I get build warning NETSDK1071 which says:

> A PackageReference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' specified a Version
>   of `2.2.3`. Specifying the version of this package is not recommended.
>   For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs

This warning is not shown when Version attribute is omitted so I was wondering how is nuget package Version resolved when not set explicitly?

Also, how does `dotnet build` knows which version of a nuget package is recommended with the current project settings?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [link](https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs) in the warning, you can learn that it is not a regular package, but Meta-package.

It's mean that this package depends on your `TargetFramework`, and this is mean that when you target to a specific framework that installed in your machine (as SDK), the package will be taken from the specific SDK.